# How to carry out repeated measures ANOVA?

Tags: repeated-measures, spss

I have the following data:

IV = 2 levels (Experimental Group + Control Group).

DV = I'm using signal detection variables i.e. (Hits, CRs, FAs & Misses)

Both groups were tested twice so therefore I have 2 sets of DVs for each group (i.e. Hits 1 & 2, CRs 1 & 2) and so on.

I want to compare between-group differences as well as within subject differences on both tests. How do I carry a repeated measures analysis?

Thanks!

Comment: What software are you going to use for that?

Comment: Hi there. I'm going to use SPSS.

Comment: Just one more thing, I originally carried out independent samples t-tests to check for differences in the DVs between the two groups. Additionally I also checked for differences between the 2 sets of DVs, i.e. was there anyy differences between Hits1 and Hits2?

Comment: I was told that I shouldn't be using multiple comparisons without a Bonferroni type correction when my variables are not independent. My supervisor suggested I use a tabular method like chi-square and a statistician has suggested repeated measures. Now I'm unsure of how to proceed!

Comment: Pointless to speak about correction for multiple comparisons - you have only 2 groups and only 2 time levels.

Answer (score 3):

OK, you have variable GROUP with 2 values and dependent variables HIT1 HIT2 CR1 CR2 FA1 FA2 MISS1 MISS2. I assume that the DVs are all interval (scale) measurement level and approximately normal distribution.

You go to General Linear - Repeated Measures menu. Enter within-subject factor name TIME with 2 levels. Enter 4 measures names: HIT, CR, FA, MISS. Press Define, allocate your DVs properly in Within-subject variables field, move GROUP in Between-subject factors field. If you Paste your syntax you will get this

```
GLM
  hit1 hit2 cr1 cr2 fa1 fa2 miss1 miss2 BY group
  /WSFACTOR = time 2 Polynomial
  /MEASURE = hit cr fa miss
  /METHOD = SSTYPE(3)
  /CRITERIA = ALPHA(.05)
  /WSDESIGN = time
  /DESIGN = group .
```

Now you may run your analysis. Find within-subject (TIME) effects and interaction effect (TIME*GROUP) in table Univariate tests. Find effect of GROUP alone in table Test of Between-subject effects.

There are also other tables, including Multivariate effects, which I won't comment on in this pretty rough instruction. Good luck.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much. This definitely answers my question. I appreciate that you answered so fast to my urgent request =)

Comment: Hi there. I have run the analysis and I have one more questions. I understand how to interpret the table for the within subject effects. However, I am confused regarding the effect of GROUP in the table Tests of Between-subject effects. I found that the effect of GROUP is significant for FA; however, how will I know if there was a differences in FA1 between GROUP 1 & 2, or if this difference is in FA2 between GROUP 1 & 2? Do I need to carry out post-hoc analyses to know which one is involved? Thanks!

Comment: One more thing. On top of the Tests of Between-subject effects, it's written "Transformed Variable: Average". Did SPSS automatically average HITS 1 & HITS 2 etc?

Comment: I want to be analyse on there were group differences on Hits 1 or 2.

Comment: Yes. In Between-subject effects table, 2 times (eg FA1 & FA2) are averaged, so it tells whether 2 groups differ on that averaged variable. To see whether groups differ on one time (eg FA1) while don't differ on the other (FA2), look TIME*GROUP interaction effect.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Can you please elaborate on your answer? I want to check if, for Group 1, there were differences in FA1 and FA2. Same for Group 2. Secondly, I want to know if, for FA1, there were differences between Group 1 and Group 2. Same thing for FA2. Sorry if I'm being a bit slow. I have never done any stats before.

Comment: What you talk about is not ANOVA task (ANOVA is omnibus test). Use t-test for independent groups separately on FA1 and FA2, and paired-samples t-test separately on group1 and group2.